# developing UWP Remote dekstop viewer

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp, remote-desktop

I wants to develop a UWP remote desktop viewer application. I had already gone through many tutorials but those are all of winform application and I can't port them into uwp. So that desktop can be viewed from windows 10 mobile. I have zero knowledge regarding this so anyone can help me from where should I start and also if someone having UWP remote desktop code so that I can understand its working easily.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot develop such application easily in the Universal Windows Platform. Microsoft has its own Remote Desktop app, but it is definitely using some APIs which are not publicly available for the connection to remote computer.

To develop such app you would need to capture / record the screen on desktop as well as capture all input and relay the input from the remote device to the source.

You could create the **desktop side** of the app using Windows Forms / WPF and connect to it remotely from a phone, which would just act as a display and would capture and send the user input to the desktop counterpart.

There is also a small chance you could implement the desktop app in UWP with the help of [Brokered Windows Runtime components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps), but that would be very tedious work.

Once again however, developing this is a major task, which is more suitable for a team of developers.

Comment: I don't want anytype of inputs for this app just a simple basic viewer app.

Comment: But you will still need a source of that "view" and for that you will need to capture the screen on the Desktop side and come up with a way to connect to it on the second device.

Comment: for pc side server part I was thinking to use code from this project (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRKFdL5eG1I) . i Just need to develop mobile client side app. well for that i have to read about protocols and networking and also have to find the replacement of methods used for client side from that video.